# Can't align my DIVs next to each other

Tags: css, alignment

For some reason I can't align my divs next to each other. "Right" goes under "left"
What is wrong with my code?
[image: Aligment issue]
**HTML**:

```
<div id="activity-container">
    <div id="activity-left">left</div>
    <div id="activity-right">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#activity-container
{
    width:90%;
    background-color:#FFFF00;
    Height:400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#activity-left {
    border: 1px solid black; 
    color:#000;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 20%; 
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
}

#activity-right {
    border: 1px solid black; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    color:#000;
    width: 80%; 
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
}
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/6we61E6n)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your borders on the `div`-s adding `2px` to their width. Remove them and they will be next to each other - [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/htxQp/)

If you *really* need the borders, then mimic them with `outline` - [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/htxQp/1/)

```css
#activity-left {
    outline: 1px solid #000;
    color:#000;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 20%; 
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
}

#activity-right {
    outline: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    color:#000;
    width: 80%; 
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
}​
```

Comment: but the borders are vanished!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the border, you can try changing the `width`:

```
#activity-container
{
width:90%;
background-color:#FFFF00;
Height:400px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#activity-left {
border: 1px solid black;
color:#000;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 19%;
float: left;
position: relative;
}

#activity-right {
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 auto;
color:#000;
width: 80%;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

Check [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pApW6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove `float` and `margin` properties from CSS

```css
#activity-right
{
    border: 1px solid black;           
    color: #000;
    width: 80%;           
    position: relative;
}
```

Than it will work as per your expectation.